# Messages based on jquery validate response

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a way to format message based on validation outcome. I have following

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("feed", function(value, element) {
    var retVal = true;
            //Ajax call here which returns 
            var retMsg = ajax()

            if(retMsg == "one") {
               //Show error as "not valid url"
            } else if(retMsg == "2") {
               //Show error as "not reachable url"
            }
    return retVal;
}, << CUSTOMIZE MESSAGE HERE BASED ON Validation OUTCOME >>);
```

Answer (score 0):

With every method in the Validate plugin, the rules are simply pass/fail.  When they fail, you get a message; when they pass, no message.  `return true` on your custom method and you passed (no message)... `return false` and you fail (message).

In the plugin, by default, "compound rules" are handled with multiple methods.  The following "compound rule" is handled with *four methods* for example...

```
rules: {
    myfield: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        minlength: 5,
        email: true
    }
}
```

However, you are attempting to make a "compound rule" with a single method.

So the logical solution is that you'd simply do it like the plugin; with two unique custom methods.  I prefer this methodology because we don't have to tamper with message placement at all.  And this is how all "compound" rules are already handled internally by the plugin.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("feedvalid", function(value, element) {
    //Ajax call here which returns 
    var retMsg = ajax()

    if (retMsg == "one") {
        return false; // failed, show message
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "not a valid url");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("feedreach", function(value, element) {
    //Ajax call here which returns 
    var retMsg = ajax()

    if (retMsg == "2")  {
        return false; // failed, show message
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "not a reachable url");
```

**Simulation:  http://jsfiddle.net/At555/**

Type a `one` or a `2` into the input field to "simulate" your ajax.

---

**The "Ugly" approach:**

Alternatively, you'd have to create & place your own message container separately from the default containers controlled by the plugin.  You'll also need logic that wipes out the message every time the field passes validation.  This solution works, but it's very unconventional so I do not prefer it.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("feed", function(value, element) {
    //Ajax call here which returns 
    var retMsg = ajax()

    if (retMsg == "one") {
        $('#myErrContainer').text("not valid url");
        return false; // failed
    } else if (retMsg == "2") {
        $('#myErrContainer').text("not reachable url");
        return false; // failed
    } else {
        $('#myErrContainer').text();
        return true; // passed
    }
}, "");
```

**Simulation:  http://jsfiddle.net/vnpG4/**

Type a `one` or a `2` into the input field to "simulate" your ajax.